# TestNG is unable to print Arabic Characters

Tags: java, testng, utf8-decode

I have to print arabic string (I'm using TestNG framework). My code is like this:

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String countryString = "المملكة العربية السعودية";
        String utfCountryString = new String(countryString.getBytes(), "utf-8");
        System.out.println("UTF String : "+utfCountryString);
        System.out.println("Original String : "+countryString);
    }
```

But when I run it using TestNG, I'm getting the following Output:

```
UTF String : ??????? ??????? ????????
Original String : ??????? ??????? ????????
PASSED: test

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

However, the output is perfectly fine if I run it under main() method or use jUnit.

Please tell me how can I run it using TestNG. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system do you use (Windows/Mac/Linux) and of what version? Might be an issue with the terminal itself.

Comment: On mac os x 10.10 with maven 3.3.3 and intellij 15 EAP, your test runs with correct ouput under testng 6.8.8, from intellij's intenal test runner, from maven in intellij terminal, and from iterm2.

I'm going to guess it probably has a lot to do with how you are invoking your tests, and what your terminal is.

So, I'll echo @RamonSnir and ask what os and jdk you're using, and add, how are you invoking?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Windows 8.1 and testng 6.8 with ant-1.9.4

Comment: @Rachit Windows famously uses ASCII for its standard Command Line. Maybe you should try an alternative terminal which supports Unicode. IIRC PowerShell can handle Unicode.

Comment: @RamonSnir The code gives issue in Eclipse too

Comment: @Batman If you're using Eclipse, then ask from the Eclipse development team for Unicode support. As said @ lscoughlin, the code itself works, and so does testng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurs when file encoding to the java compiler is not defined for UTF-8 encoding. As you mentioned you are using Ant as build tool, define the following encoding in build.xml file.

```
<javac ... encoding="UTF-8" ... />
```

Tested and working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try by pasting the following in your build file:

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="${classes.dir}" encoding="UTF-8"
    includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}"
    srcdir="src">
    <src path="src" />
    <classpath refid="Dummy.classpath" />
</javac>
```